How do I provide a URL link to a specific ID in a web page in a PDF?
I want to link to a specific section of a page from a PDF. The page has an ID at the section I want to link to. Specifically, the link is https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality
That text is in my PDF. When I try to click or ctrl-click or command-click on the link, the browser shows the URL as:
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php%23quality
and the link reports page not found. This happens both in Chrome and Safari. If I edit the URL in the browser and replace the %023 with #, the link works correctly.
How do I get the octothorpe to transmit properly to the browser?
I created a PDF containing the text:
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality
I opened the PDF in a browser and clicked on the link. Also tried ctrl-click in Windows and command-click in MacOS.
The default browser opens and shows the URL as:
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php%23quality
The browser reports 'page not found'. If I edit the URL and replace %23 with #, the link works correctly.
Tried this from Adobe Reader also and got the same result.

It may be a quirk in MS Word.

I generated a word file with a footnote that contains a link. When I save that as a PDF everything works just fine. But when I take the original document (14 pages) and strip out everything but the text that references the footnote and the footnote, and save it as a PDF, it changes the link to %23.

Dropbox has a basic link in a footnote (Link.docx, Link.pdf) and the extract from the original document with the footnote link (Link2.docx, Link2.pdf). The docx files were saved to pdf from MS Word. It is interesting that although the process of producing the pdf was basically the same in both cases, Dropbox shows the link that works as a pdf icon while the test file is displayed as the entire page. Dropbox link is https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/apaxg1yjmo2gyt8c293f8/AMSWpmGTPFd1lkcwfNuyzNI?rlkey=6625y3q7nejoq1cdzch9wiz9c&st=alp16djy&dl=0

The original 14 page pdf is also on dropbox. Named JPG Compression Study 20220206.pdf. Footnote 2 is on page 4 and is resolved at the end of the document.

The problem was in MS Word. When I wrote the document a couple years ago I copied the URL I wanted to reference and pasted it into the document as a footnote (actually an endnote). It showed up with the text I wanted with the #.
When I went back to the document and right-clicked on the endnote I could then look at the hyperlink, which had %23. I changed that to # and resaved the document as a PDF and it now works. So MS Word changed the # to %23 without telling me and didn't show it in the hyperlink text. Thanks for reminding me about the difference between the hyperlink and hyperlink text.

NOTE: MS Word produces bloated PDF files. When I saved my document as a PDF using word, it came out 70 Mbytes. When I went to the Adobe site and used their word -> PDF converter it came out 1.6 Mbytes. I was storing the document in a forum which had a 20 Mbyte limit so I needed the smaller file.

Answer is in the comments above. Pay attention to the difference between a hyperlink and the hyperlink text.
